# LSTM Time Series forecasting

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I've been working on a time series forecasting project using LSTM (Long Short-Term Memory) by following a YouTube tutorial. My dataset consists of NDVI (Normalized Difference Vegetation Index) values over time. The model I've implemented seems to work well for training and testing on historical data, but I'm struggling to make it predict future values beyond the test dataset.
Any advice, code examples, or recommended resources would be greatly appreciated.
This is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'NDVI.csv')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date time'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
NDVI = df['NDVI']

def df_to_X_y(df, window_size=3):
    df_as_np = df.to_numpy()
    X = []
    y = []
    for i in range(len(df_as_np)-window_size):
        row = [[a] for a in df_as_np[i:i+3]]
        X.append(row)
        label = df_as_np[i+3]
        y.append(label)
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)

WINDOW_SIZE=3
X,y= df_to_X_y(NDVI, WINDOW_SIZE)
X.shape, y.shape

X_train, y_train = X[:410], y[:410]
X_val, y_val= X[410:456], y[410:456]
X_test, y_test = X[456:], y[456:]
X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint# for Saving models
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import RootMeanSquaredError
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(InputLayer((3, 1)))
model1.add(LSTM(64))
model1.add(Dense(8, 'relu'))
model1.add(Dense(1, 'linear'))

model1.summary()

cp = ModelCheckpoint('NDVImodel/', save_best_only=True)

model1.compile(loss=MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01), metrics=[RootMeanSquaredError()])
model1.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=20, callbacks=[cp])
train_predictions = model1.predict(X_train).flatten()
train_results=pd.DataFrame(data={'Train Predictions': train_predictions, 'Actuals':y_train})

val_predictions = model1.predict(X_val).flatten()
val_results = pd.DataFrame(data={'Val Predictions':val_predictions, 'Actuals':y_val})
val_results
plt.plot(val_results['Val Predictions'])
plt.plot(val_results['Actuals'])  #the results of this are what displayed in the image
```

Comment: Your window size of 3 is very small. Maybe the model can't learn the bigger picture to predict future values.

Comment: @mhenning I changed it to 12 and yes I got better results. However I still don't know how to extend the prediction (for example to 20 future results)

Comment: Do you not know how to predict e.g. 20 values, or is the prection bad, or is there an error? Also, did you try to increase the epochs and batch size?

Answer (score 0):

Your output has a single unit so the output has only single value. As I see you are using Sequential to Vector network if you want next n values you need to predict the test set then get the single predicted value and append that value and the predict again and continue the process until you have 12 new values. but this method gives a lot of variance as the new values continue getting added.

If you want to use a Sequence to sequence network you use the `LSTM(64,return_sequences=True)` then use the Dense layer `Dense(12,"relu")` you want. This returns the sequences and then you can apply your loss functions on the sequences returned by Dense layer. But for this you also have to modify the target values, for there are two functions both in numpy and tensorflow.

`np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(window_shape=dense_output+1)`
`tf.data.Dataset.window(size=dense_output+1)`

```py
def create_seq_ds(np_series,sequence_length=30,output_size=12,batch_size=16,shuffle=False):
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np_series)
    ds = ds.window(size=output_size+1,shift=1,drop_remainder=True).flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(output_size+1))
    ds = ds.window(size=sequence_length,shift=1,drop_remainder=True).flat_map(lambda x:x.batch(sequence_length))
    ds = ds.map(lambda x: (x[:,0],x[:,1:,target_col])) # (input,output seq)
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(4*batch_size)
    return ds.batch(batch_size)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=[None,1]))
model.add(LSTM(64,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(seq_length))
```